# how should i go about writing this aritmetic progression topic in LaTex?

Tags: overleaf

Assignment part 3 [20 marks equivalent to 5%] 
The fourth and tenth terms of an arithmetic progression are defined by T_4=7x+8  
   T_10=19x+14 
a) Determine expressions for the first term and the common difference. [4]
b) If the sum of the first fifteen terms of this progression is 630, find the value of the thirtieth term. [6]

```
Determine expressions for the first term and the common difference.<br />
```

Let a be the first term and d be the common difference of an A.P., accordingly: 
T4 = 7x +8.
or a+ 3d = 7x+8……………… (equation 1).
T10 = 19x + 14.
or a+ 9d = 19x+14……………. (equation 2).
Subtracting equation. (1) from equation. (2).
6d = 12x + 6. => d = 2x+1., putting d=2x+1 in equation. (1).
a + 6x+3 = 7x+8. => a= x+5.

Therefore, the first term (a) = x +5 = 2+5 = 7., Answer
common difference (d)= 2x+1 = 2×2 +1 = 5., Answer.

```
If the sum of the first fifteen terms of this progression is 630, find the value of the thirtieth term.<br />
```

Sn = n/2 [a1 + an]
S15 = 15/2. {2a + 14.d} = 630.
or a+7d = 42.
or x+5 +14x+7 = 42.
or 15x = 30 => x= 30/15 = 2.
T30 = a + 29d = 7 + 29×5 = 152. Answer.

Another way 
a) Determine expressions for the first term and the common difference.
AP 
Tn=a+(n-1) d 
T4 =a+3d =7x+8 
T10=a+9d=19x+14 
T10 -T4= 6d=12x+6 
3d=6x+3 
d=2x+1 answer

T4=a+3d=a+3×(2x+1) =7x+8 
a+6x+3=7x+8
a = x+5 answer

b) If the sum of the first fifteen terms of this progression is 630, find the value of the thirtieth term. 
Sn = n/2 [a1 + an] 
S15=15/2 [(2(x+5) +14(2x+1)] 
=15/2 (2x+10+28x+14) 
15/2(30x+24) =630

30x+24=630×2/15 =84 
30x+24=84
30x=60
x=2
a=x+5=2+5=7…… answer for a
d=2x+1=2×2+1=5……… answer for d
T30=a+29d =7+29×5=152 …………T30=152 answer

Another way
a) Determine expressions for the first term and the common difference.

In the AP, T4 = 7x+8 = a+3d … (1) and
T10 = 19x+14 = a+9d … (2)
From (1) and (2): 6d = 12x+6 or d = 2x+1. answer
From (1): 7x+8 = a+6x+3, or a = x+5. Answer
So, in the AP, a = 7 and d = 5.

b) If the sum of the first fifteen terms of this progression is 630, find the value of the thirtieth term.
Sn = n/2 [a1 + an]
S15 = (15/2) [2(x+5) + 14(2x+1)] = 15[(x+5) +7(2x+1)]
= 15[15x+12] = 630, or
45[5x+4] = 630, or 5x+4 = 14, or 5x = 10 or x = 2.
So, in the AP, a = 7 and d = 5.
And T30 = a+29d = 7+145 = 152. answer

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX. You should first provide a minimal working example demonstrating how you have tried to fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome. // Please clarify what you do want to achieve. E.g. just some text with formulas, as a kind of protocol? Formulating tasks for students? Etc. // And please post your Latex-attempts, which makes it easier for all of us. Thank you